# Swing GUI appending colored text in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, text-coloring, android-textattributes

```
public static void setJTextPaneFont(JTextPane jtp, Color c, int from, int to) {
    // Start with the current input attributes for the JTextPane. This
    // should ensure that we do not wipe out any existing attributes
    // (such as alignment or other paragraph attributes) currently
    // set on the text area.
    MutableAttributeSet attrs = jtp.getInputAttributes();

    // Set the font color
    StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, c);

    // Retrieve the pane's document object
    StyledDocument doc = jtp.getStyledDocument();

    // Replace the style for the entire document. We exceed the length
    // of the document by 1 so that text entered at the end of the
    // document uses the attributes.
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(from, to, attrs, false);
}
```

The purpose of the above piece of code is to change the color of a particular line of code between two indices, from and to. After the call to this function, the text and color in `JTextPane` gets updated correctly(a particular line).

[image]

However, when I try to refresh the `JTextPane` with new texts(by emptying the `jtextpane` and re-appending new text), all text automatically gets painted into the color last assigned when called with `setJTextPaneFont`.

[image]

Basically, instead of just having a few colored lines, the whole document(new one) becomes colored without ever making a call to the function above. Therefore I suspect that the attributes of `JTextPane` somehow got modified.

So the question is, how would I be able to reset the `JTextPane` back to default attributes?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: Not sure if I could make it less complicated. Thanks though.

Comment: *"Not sure if I could make it less complicated."* It is not Complete, Verifiable or an Example.

Comment: Appreciate the comment.

Comment: Hope this is slightly better. Please let me know where I should specify a bit more.

Comment: please where is the MCVE/SSCCE, really depends of whats JTextPane contains, voting to close too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
public void setJTextPaneFont(JTextPane jtp, Color c, int from, int to) {
            // Start with the current input attributes for the JTextPane. This
            // should ensure that we do not wipe out any existing attributes
            // (such as alignment or other paragraph attributes) currently
            // set on the text area.

            StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();

          // MutableAttributeSet attrs = jtp.getInputAttributes();

            AttributeSet attrs = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);
            // Set the font color
            //StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, c);

            // Retrieve the pane's document object
            StyledDocument doc = jtp.getStyledDocument();
            // System.out.println(doc.getLength());

            // Replace the style for the entire document. We exceed the length
            // of the document by 1 so that text entered at the end of the
            // document uses the attributes.
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(from, to, attrs, true);
        }
```

Comment: dosn't not solve 3/4 of potentials problems with JTextPane (in the near future)

Answer (score 3):

The *emptying the jtextpane and re-appending new text* problem could be solved multiple ways:

Call `doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 1, attrs, true);`
and pass an empty AttributeSet here

Recreate the document and instead of `doc.remove()/insert()` call `jtp.setDocument(jtp.getEditorKit().createDefaultDocument())`

Clear input Attributes. Add a caret listener and check whether the document is empty. When it's empty remove all the desired attributes.